# Create New Distinct List(of T) from Existing List(of T) Using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, distinct

How can I get a new distinct list from an existing list using LINQ?  This is what I have so far and it is not distinct but does give me a new list.

```
Dim tmpQryColumn = (From a In _allAudits 
                    Select New CheckBoxListItem 
                    With {.Id = a.AuditColumn, .Name = a.AuditColumn} 
                    ).Distinct()
_columnList = New List(Of CheckBoxListItem)(tmpQryColumn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `CheckboxListItem` doesn't override `Equals`/`GetHashCode` so any two instances are effectively distinct. Try:

```
Dim columns = (From a In _allAudits
               Select a.AuditColumn).Distinct()

_columnList = (From column in columns
               Select New CheckBoxListItem 
               With {.Id = column, .Name = column} 
               ).ToList()
```

I'm sure there's a simpler way of writing it in VB, but I'm not familiar enough with the syntax to write it. The C# version would be:

```
_columnList = _allAudits.Select(x => x.AuditColumn)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Select(x => new CheckboxListItem { Id = x, Name = x })
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Distinct` extension method relies on the types in question properly implementing value equality.  The most likely reason that it's failing here is that `CheckBoxListItem` doesn't implement equality based on the `Id` and `Name` properties.

To fix this do one of the following

1. Implement equality semantics for `CheckBoxListItem`
2. Create an `IEqualityComparer<CheckBoxListItem>` and use the overload of `Distinct` which takes that value